# Jqgrid and navgrid search button

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a table (generated with JSON POST datas) created with jqGrid. The navigation works very well.
I set the option to display the search button.

When I click on the options displayed ... but no research is done ...

Do the research is done with Javascript in the array elements, or does it specify a URL to search in Ajax?

here is my code.

```
<div id="liste">
<div id="messagebox"></div>
<div id="filter"></div>
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'/admin/statistique/getjson/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['','Nom','Visites Totales', 'Visites Uniques','Contact'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'edition',index:'edition', sortable:false,editable: false,width:15, align:"center"},
            {name:'etablissement_nomAMarrakech',index:'etablissement_nomAMarrakech', sortable:true, editable: false,width:150, align:"center"},
            {name:'',index:'', sortable:false, editable: false,width:200, align:"center"},
            {name:'',index:'', sortable:false, editable: false,width:200, align:"center"},
            {name:'',index:'', sortable:false, editable: false,width:240, align:"center"}
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,25,50,100,300],
        sortname: 'etablissement_nomAMarrakech',
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        gridview : true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Aperçu des statistiques"
    });

    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false});         
});

</script>
```

Here is a screen

[image: Generated Grid]

As you can see, when I submit the form, JQGrid write "Loading..." but no line is check...

Sincerely,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
name:'',index:''
```

in the definition of three columns of the grid. It is wrong. You can compare is with the code where you try to declare class with three properties with the name ''.

The `name` property is mandatory. It must be unique, can't be equal to one from reserved names ('rn', 'cb' and 'subgrid') and should not contain any meta-characters used in jQuery selectors like '.', ' ' and so on (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).

Moreover if you use `datatype: 'json'` without `loadonce: true` the server will be responsible for the data filtering. On search request the new request to the server will be send which has additional 
parameters like `&searchField=edition&searchString=Spa&searchOper=cn`. The server should return back to the jqGrid the filtered data.

Comment: Nice help and resource. Thank you very much. Now I know there is param like searchString... I test and it Works.